# Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to connect to MongoDB from PHP but I keep getting the fatal error in the title. My PHP version is 5.5.14, architecture x86, thread safety enabled, VC11.

So I downloaded 5.5 Thread Safe (TS) x86 from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.6/windows), extracted php_mongo.dll to the `\ext\` folder of my php installation, added `extension=php_mongo.dll` to the php.ini file, and restarted Apache.

I keep getting the same fatal error when I use either `Mongo()` and `MongoClient()`.

Also, I can access mongo from CMD, starting it with `mongod` and then opening another cmd window to handle the database using `mongo`. I installed PHP and Apache separately (No XAMPP or WAMP) on Windows 8.1 x64.

Installation folders:

- Apache: `C:\Apache24`
- PHP: `C:\php`
- MongoDB: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB`

Comment: did you get the answer @creativasium

Answer (score -1):

In the lastest version, you can use new MongoDB\Driver\Manager() to create the obj instead of the MongoClient().